# Typeahead Component AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a typeahead component in my application as shown below

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="ProductsCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" />

      <div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
         <input type="text" ng-model="product"
                typeahead="product as (product.description) for product in fetchProduct($viewValue)" />
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Since I will be using the product typeahead component in different parts of my application, I placed the fetchProduct function into a separate controller. However, I need to define the "TypeaheadCtrl" together with the component each time I want to use it.

Can I create a directive like shown below to encapsulate the component?

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="ProductsCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" />

      <div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
         <input type="text" ng-model="product" product-typeahead />
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What if you put the fetchProduct into a service? That way it can be used anywhere it can be injected, including your typeahead directive?

Comment: I understand what you mean but that would mean I still have to manually assign the service to my scope..  ProductsCtrl($scope, ProductFetch) { $scope.fetchProduct = ProductFetch });

Comment: Is that a issue? That wrapper directive would do that. But any consumer of that wrapper directive wouldn't.